# PDF doesn't open in any edit mode in Acrobat Reader when opened from Outlook

Tags: 2010, outlook, pdf

I have a document library that holds .pdf's. When the user opens the files on SharePoint they open in edit mode just fine. They can edit them, save, and changes show up when the document opens again.

The problem is there is a workflow that sends an email to the user. In the email is the link to the document. When they open the document that way it doesn't look like it's editable.

Is there some setting I am missing to where IE doesn't like documents opened from Outlook or something?

[image]

It's the OOB information at the bottom of an approval task

Comment: Can you show the link to the document that is sent to your email?

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa see edit